# Add glow effect to traffic light Imageprocessing skimage

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I am learning image processing and came across this following code. What it does is glow the red light of the trafficlights image. I did understood the code by don't know how the new_R variable is calculated. Although it is easy to interpret that it corresponds to value in R and G scale where the values of pixel is less than 40 in R and 10 in G.
I just want to know why G layer values are added and what if i want to glow the green light or orange light what should be the upper or lower bound in calculation of new_G or new_O as new_R is done.

```
from sklearn import io as ip
import numpy as np

I = ip.imread('trafficlights.png')

R = np.logical_and(I[:, :, 0] > 40, I[:, :, 1] < 10)

new_R = gaussian_filt(255 * R, 30)

J = I.copy()
J[:, :, 0] = ip.imadd(new_R, J[:, :, 0])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

plt.sca(ax[0])
ip.imshow(I)

plt.sca(ax[1])
ip.imshow(J)
ip.imsave('traffic_redglow.png', J)
```

if you want to reproduce then here are the other functions

```
def imadd(I, K):
'''
Add to the pixels of I.
- If K is a number, adds K to each pixel value of I.
- If K is an image (NumPy array) of the same size as I,
    the pixel values of K are added to the pixel values of I.
    
Clips the result to avoid overflow.

Example:
# Add 10 to each pixel of I
J = imadd(I, 10)

# Subtract 20 from each pixel of I
J = imadd(I, -20)

# Add images I1 and I2 together
J = imadd(I1, I2)
'''
import numbers
if isinstance(K, numbers.Number):
    J = I.astype('int32')
    J += K
elif isinstance(K, np.ndarray):
    assert K.shape == I.shape, f'Cannot add images with sizes {I.shape} and {K.shape}.'
    J = I.astype('int32') + K.astype('int32')
else:
    raise TypeError('K must be a number or an array.')
    
np.clip(J, 0, 255, out=J)
J = J.astype('uint8')
return J

def gaussian_filt(I, sigma, pad=0):
'''
Filters the image I with a Gaussian filter,
with standard deviation sigma.
Returns a new filtered image.

Optional argument pad specifies the boundary options,
and can take the following values:
- if pad is a number (0-255, default 0), pixels outside the bounds of the image are assigned this value.
- 'reflect': outer pixel values are mirror-reflections of inner pixel values
across the image border.
- 'nearest': outer pixel values are equal to the nearest inner pixel values.
- 'wrap': outer pixel values are computed by assuming that the image is periodic (i.e. tiled).

Example:
# Use Gaussian filter on I with a standard deviation of 0.5,
# pad boundary pixels with white
J = gaussian_filt(I, 0.5, pad=255)

# Reflect boundary pixel values across the image border
J = gaussian_filt(I, 0.5, pad='reflect')
'''
import numbers
assert isinstance(pad, numbers.Number) or pad in ['reflect', 'nearest', 'wrap'], \
        'Choose a correct value for pad: a number (0-255), ''reflect'', ''nearest'', or ''wrap''.'

if isinstance(pad, numbers.Number):
    md = 'constant'
    c = pad
else:
    md = pad
    c = 0
    
return gaussian_filter(I, sigma, mode=md, cval=c)
```

[image: the image to glow]

[image: glow image]

Thanks a lot for going through

Comment: Please provide both input and output image. Thank you.

Comment: "Add glow effect": what ???